# Why is $Y e^{i\omega t}$ called an "elementary process"

Tags: stochastic-processes

In my seminar, we encountered the process:

> $X_t = Y e^{i\omega t}$, $t\in \mathbb R$, $Y$ centered complex random variable with $E|Y|^2 = \sigma < \infty$, $\omega \in \mathbb R$ is a constant

and the supporting materials called this process an *elementary process*.

Why is this so? In what sense is the process elementary?

Thank you.

Comment: Elementary typically refers to step functions. Is that relevant at all?

Comment: @avid19 Well it certainly doesn't seem to be relevant, this process seems to circle around the circle with diameter $Y$, don't see the step function hidden in there